# Event to be happen in past but not happened

Tags: sentence-construction

I saw my mom at home instead when she should have been at the Bank. She had a plan to go to the Bank. She told me that she was going to the Bank.

Actualy i want to ask her about her plan in second sentence

What she is doing at home when she had planed to go to bank

Should I say:

> "What you are doing here. you had to go to bank, hand't you?"
>   Or
>   "What you are doing here. you were to go to bank, weren't you?"

Or should I say some thing else?

Comment: What are you doing here? You were supposed to go to the Bank.

Comment: Stop *Indianizing* there. I get upset when someone puts *na* (meaning hadn't you here) as a question tag!

Comment: @MaulikV: Don't get upset, some people _do_ like it :) You should think of your heart na? :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are surprised by your mother's **presence** in the house and not bothered what is **she doing** inside the house.

So, keep it short -

> Why are you **here** instead of (being in) the **bank?**

When you and her both know the bank's plan, you don't need to specify the event - *you were supposed to*. **It's understood** with the above-mentioned sentence.

**After OP's edit**

Okay, if you want to make her realize about her plan, tell...

> Why are you here? You had a plan to go to the bank, handn't you?

**After OP asking me in Hindi**

> What are you doing here? You were supposed to go to the Bank, weren't you? (Jim's comment).

Comment: Actualy i want to ask her about her plan in second sentence
What she is doing at home when she had planed to go to bank

Comment: @user4084 well, you added it now!

Comment: yes maulikv in hindi if i say "tum gharme kya kar rahe ho. tum to bank jane wale the na" how i would say it in English

Comment: @user4084 Ah, that way. Go with Jim's comment. That translates this!